# How to control number of digits in exponent with sprintf in R?

Tags: r, printf

This R code produces the following:

```
> sprintf("%.6e", c(5, 50, 500, 5000))
[1] ""5.000000e+00" "5.000000e+01" "5.000000e+02" "5.000000e+03"
```

But I would like to have three digits in the exponent (after the "e+") like this:

```
"5.000000e+000" "5.000000e+001" "5.000000e+002" "5.000000e+003"
```

Comment: How about `sub('([1-9])$', '0\\1', sprintf("%.6e", c(50, 500, 5000)))#[1] "5.000000e+001" "5.000000e+002" "5.000000e+003"`

Comment: Thanks so much, that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is an option with `sub` after making the changes with `sprintf` to insert 0 before the last element in the string after the `sprintf` formatting

```
sub('([0-9])$', '0\\1',  sprintf("%.6e", c(5, 50, 500, 5000)))
#[1] "5.000000e+000" "5.000000e+001" "5.000000e+002" "5.000000e+003"
```

Comment: Sorry, I also should have included 5 as an example in my original question (now edited).   Please change "1-9" to "0-9" in the first argument of  ```sub```, so that that 5 will be printed as 5.000000e+000.  Then I will accept as answer.

Comment: @ThetaFC thanks, I changed it.  I thought you wanted to have the 0s only printed once.